# Como colocar 2 elementos concatenados com variável em um seletor com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho 2 variáveis e desejo colocar as mesmas concatenadas em apenas um seletor com jQuery:

Sei que é possível fazer assim:

```
$(".classe1, .classe2").append(...);
```

Mas eu desejo concatenar essas duas classes com uma variável e colocar os dois dentro de um seletor mais ou menos assim(este exemplo está dando erro):

```
var to = $(".meunome").attr("id");
var from = $(".amigonome").attr("id");

$(".classe1'+to+', .classe2'+from+'").append(...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você obteve o id, então tem que usar o '#' como seletor:

```
var to = $(".meunome").attr("id");
var from = $(".amigonome").attr("id");

$('#' + to + ', #' + from).append(...);
```

Comment: +1 Note que se existirem mais de um elemento com a classe `meunome` e/ou mais de um com a classe `amigonome`, esse código apenas selecionará o primeiro de cada conjunto.